# Using Openseadragon on SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, xml, api, sharepoint-2013

Has anyone been successful using Openseadragon for data visualization on SharePoint 2013?  I'm attempting to leverage JS API to call the list and iterate through the data to display pictures (contained in the list) on the screen. I looked at the Openseadragon documentation: http://openseadragon.github.io/#examples-and-features and a great GitHub repo demo: https://github.com/seajax/seajax.github.io but I'm missing how to loop the list data.

Would it be easier to convert the list to XML format and then call it in the body ?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Pivot Ajax</title> 
    <!-- The built PivotViewer script --> 
    <script src="seadragon-pivot-standalone-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PivotView.css"/> 
    <style> 
       html { 
       font-family:sans-serif; 
           font-size:0.875em; 
       }
       html, body { 
           height: 100%; 
           position: relative; 
           margin: 0; 
       } 
       #theviewer { 
           position: absolute; 
           top: 0; 
           bottom: 0; 
           left: 0; 
           right: 0; 
           border: 2px solid gray; 
       } 
     </style> 
     </head> 

<script>
    $.ajax({

        var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

        $.ajax({
           url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items",
           method: "GET",
           headers: { "Accept":  "application/json; odata=verbose"  },
           success: function  (data) {

                if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                }        
          },
          error: function  (data) {
              alert("Error: "+ data);
                 }
          });
    });
</script>
<body>
  <div id="theviewer" class="pivot_ajax_viewer" data-use-hash="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note to point out that Seajax and OpenSeadragon, while originating from the same project originally, are now quite different from each other. Looks like you're using Seajax... You might try also posting your question here: https://github.com/seajax/seajax/issues (though it doesn't look very active).

Comment: @iangilman Thanks.  I will research the documentation and post in the seajax forum if I'm unable to find a solution soon.

Comment: Sounds good. For what it's worth we'd love to have a Pivot viewer based on OpenSeadragon, but no one has built such a thing.